# How to iterate through attribute visibility with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a point shapefile with a timestamp that I would like to turn off and turn back on 1 by 1 with a new element of the attribute table appearing every second

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Is this static or dynamic data. Do you just want to animate the map for an existing table? If so check the time manager plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/

Comment: timemanager looks perfect thanks but I am getting an error that my string formatting is wrong, but it is "YYYY:MM:DD hh:mm:ss" and giving me an error An error occured while trying to add layer myLayer to TimeManager. Cause: Exception(UnsupportedFormatException("Could not match value 2016:01:23 10:53:16 with any of the supported formats. Tried ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', '%Y-%m-%dT%HZ', ........ etc

Comment: I have figured out how to increment by day but not by hour, but I think I should be okay